# Potential Visual Studio Issue: Can't resolve symbol but works fine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, symbols

I feel like either this is an issue in Visual Studio or I'm crazy.

### Ingredients

I'm using:

- Visual Studio Professional 2012 (11.0.61030.00) Update 4
- ReSharper 7
- xUnit for tests
- FluentAssertions in my test code.

### The Issue

Just recently, resharper showed me an issue:

[image]

I navigated to the file, and sure enough, there seemed to be the issue in the code.

[image]

But I'm referencing FluentAssertions:

[image]

And if I clean and rebuild the entire solution, I get no errors:

[image]

And all of the tests even run correctly:

[image]

### Questions

- Why would this just start showing up after installing Visual Studio Update 4?
- What can I do to make it go away?
- Is there actually a problem with something, or if tests & code run fine and no errors appear, is it not an issue at all?

First time I've seen anything like this so I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be for several reasons, such as NuGet package restore - if the packages (and therefore the assemblies) weren't there when the solution was opened, ReSharper will mark them as undefined. It's usually pretty good at noticing and reindexing when the assemblies are added, but perhaps it missed them here. Sometimes opening the file again will cause the errors to be reindexed, sometimes it requires the solution to be closed and reopened.

Alternatively, and what is probably the most likely way to fix, is to go to ReSharper -> Options -> General and click Clear Caches. ReSharper will rebuild the solution cache, and should reindex everything and get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the solution appears to be the old "Restart the PC" trick.

If anyone knows how an issue such as this could be resolved *without* restarting the PC, I'm happy to award you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have any old missing references, just noticed on my solution the same issue removing old missing references did the trick for me.